# Entry Level Field Mixer

Tags: field, mixer, gear

Hi, I'm wondering what a entry level field mixer would be/cost?

I'd like to have an indoor recording package and have a Zoom for recorder but the pre-amps are too noisy for what I can tolerate.  I'm looking for something with as few as 2 great preamps.  I'm hoping not to spend more than 400 for it.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the Sound Devices MixPre.  It is more money then you are suggesting but it is a dynamite piece of gear.  The company recently launch the next evolution of the product line with the MixPre-D, so if you search around second hand sites you might be able to find a used Mixpre cheap as people upgrade.  They are the kind of thing that last forever though so you won't find one too cheap.  It is worth the price though as it is a well made and reliable device.

Comment: What about Sound Devices mm1?

Comment: That is a good product too, but only gives you one channel on mic pre.  The mix pre has two channels. If you are using a mono mic then the mm1 should get you started 

Comment: I was adding it up and the two mm1's equal a mix-pre.  Does anyone ever use the headphone knobs on their mp-1 or mix pre when they can just use from the recorder?  

Comment: I prefer to listen from the recorder, as once in a blue moon the connection between the mixer and recorder can crap out on you. You can always connect the output of the recorder to the tape return on the mixer and monitor that way.